# There is any way to simulate an arduino due?

Tags: programming, arduino-due, simulator

As the title says there is any program that can simulate an arduino due? I like the design of Proteus 8 but he can't simulate it. Only the arduino Uno R3, Mega and another one that I forgot the name.